# Sharing Background across item rows Android ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-framelayout

How can I generate the following layout in an Android list view ?

I need the background of a divider to be a gradient stretching across different items. Is this possible?

[image]

Comment: Depends on how many items the background is long, but i think it could be possible if it changes only on the first three for example

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve this just extend an adapter, like BaseAdapter and do something like this:

```
int[] drawables = {R.drawable.back_one, R.drawable.back_two, R.drawable.back_three};

@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    .....check if view is null otherwise inflate a new layout.....

    if(drawables.length < 3) {
        //You can assign one of the backgrounds
        view.setBackdroundResource(drawables[i]);
    }

}
```